# Formatting announcements in seed file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a website where I have section called announcements.  The point is, as you realize, to have user input announcements for clients to see.  The problem that I am facing is how do I save all the formatting that user does, ex new line.  In form under views (announcements) I have the content as this:

```
<%= f.label :content %>
<%= f.text_area :content, :size => '100x20', :required => 'required', :pattern => ValidationValues.c_content %>
```

Now if I were to create a new announcement it gets submitted through controller and it saves.  All works as intended except that the new lines are not saved.

How can I save those new lines?

Also how do I represent the new line character in the seed file?

Answer (score 1):

Rails has a few built in methods to help with this.[Raw](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw) and [simple_format](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#M002285)